# Wordpress Woocommerce Short codes not running

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add woocommerce to my website but the shortcodes within the pages aren't running.

I've installed and activated and most of the settings have been left default. In my page.php file I have the following:

```
<?php do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_cart]' ); ?>
```

I'm certain it's opening the correct template page because I can add random text.

I was getting the content before but changed it to the above to simplify everything. I've tried wiping my functions.php incase something was trying to stop it but still nothing shows.

From my understanding by running that shortcode it should route towards the template/cart.php file within my woocommerce plugin, but all it returns is a blank page.

Comment: Check your WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout. I'm pretty sure you have to point it towards a particular page in order for it to route it. Same goes for the checkout pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_shortcode()` returns stuff, you need to echo:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_cart]' );
```